# Release Plugin - How to put Release Candidate in Snapshot directory

Tags: maven, release-management

I would like to use the Maven Release Plugin to release Release Candidates to my Nexus Snapshot repository.

It's not a problem to deploy RC's to Nexus but I would like to utilise the workflow offered by `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`.

The problem I am facing is that my proposed pattern (`1.2.3-RC1`) is not allowed by the plugin. Only the regular version pattern is accepted and these go the "releases" Nexus repository.

How can I get the Release Plugin to put my Release Candidates in the SNAPSHOT repository instead of releases?

** Please Note: ** My company/another team uses the snapshots to store RC's and only approved releases go into releases. They don't use the staging feature of Nexus.

I'm not sure how the others put the RC's into Snapshots repo but it looks like they may use a regular "deploy" which I want to avoid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maven, SNAPSHOT is something that may be different every time you build it. A release build will always produce the same result. In this sense, a release candidate is a release, not a snapshot - it has been tagged, it has no SNAPSHOT dependencies, it is reproducible. It does not mean it is ready to go to production - it is just a reproducible build. As long as the release plugin is concerned, you are building a release.

If you want to keep the release invisible for others, you might be interested in the Nexus staged repositories: http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html.

> The staging suite in Nexus Pro allows an organization to create a
>   temporary staging repository and to manage the promotion of components
>   from a staging repository to a release repository

.